# C# .net Webservice: XML to SOAP translation with XSLT

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt, soap

I'm receiving XML API-Calls that I need to translate to SOAP before my asmx consumes the messages and spits them back out as XML again. All my calls are similar but have some minor differences so I'd like some universal XSLT that convers them all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Request>
    <Authentication>
        <ProtocolVersion>1.0</ProtocolVersion>
        <RequestId>20200616084403_8340052817_89747</RequestId>
        <DateTime>2020-06-16 08:44:03</DateTime>
        <MessageHash>9d1a99373d773520f70dc9a0</MessageHash>
        <PointOfSale>
            <TerminalId>123456789</TerminalId>
            <DeviceId>123</DeviceId>
        </PointOfSale>
    </Authentication>
    <PaymentRequest>
        <AccountName>MyName</AccountName>
        <FullTrackData>Data</FullTrackData>
        <Amount>1</Amount>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
    </PaymentRequest>
</Request>
```

My goal is to get:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="https://webapi.example.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <web:Authentication>
         <web:ProtocolVersion>1.0</web:ProtocolVersion>
         <web:RequestId>2ce9764e-9365-41e6-be1a-f465d5157049</web:RequestId>
         <web:DateTime>2020-06-23T13:48:15.483+02:00</web:DateTime>
         <web:MessageHash>9d1a99373d773520f70dc9a0</web:MessageHash>
         <web:PointOfSale>
            <web:TerminalId>123456789</web:TerminalId>
            <web:DeviceId>123</web:DeviceId>
         </web:PointOfSale>
      </web:Authentication>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:Payment>
         <web:Request>
            <web:AccountName>MyName</web:AccountName>
            <web:FullTrackData>Data</web:FullTrackData>
            <web:Amount>100</web:Amount>
            <web:Currency>EUR</web:Currency>
         </web:Request>
      </web:Payment>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

One thing to note Amount in the XML is EUR while the Amount in the SOAP XML is Euro-Cent (factor 100).

I'm also looking for some way to understand the whole concept if at all possible. How do I select something further down the tree? How do I copy data within these nodes? How do I attach the namespace shortcut (web:) to the tags and how do I make that kind of unversal over similar requests?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Looking quickly at your input and expected output it seems to be a simple mapping of the elements to new names.

Answer (score 1):

So I've read through the XSLT introduction on w3schools and several other posts here and finally found something that works.

I don't like my solution though. I want this to be way more generic than it actually is. Is there any chance to achieve that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="https://webapi.example.com">
            <soapenv:Header>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Request/Authentication"/>          
            </soapenv:Header>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Request/PaymentRequest"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Request/ReloadRequest"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Request/RefundRequest"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Request/BalanceRequest"/>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template xmlns:web="https://webapi.example.com" match="Authentication">
        <web:Authentication>
            <web:ProtocolVersion><xsl:value-of select="//ProtocolVersion"/></web:ProtocolVersion>
            <web:RequestId><xsl:value-of select="//RequestId"/></web:RequestId>
            <web:DateTime><xsl:value-of select="//DateTime"/></web:DateTime>
            <web:MessageHash><xsl:value-of select="//MessageHash"/></web:MessageHash>
            <web:PointOfSale>
                <web:TerminalId><xsl:value-of select="//TerminalId"/></web:TerminalId>
                <web:DeviceId><xsl:value-of select="//DeviceId"/></web:DeviceId>
            </web:PointOfSale>
        </web:Authentication>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template xmlns:web="https://webapi.example.com" match="PaymentRequest">
        <web:Payment>
            <web:Request>
                <web:AccountName><xsl:value-of select="//AccountName"/></web:AccountName>
                <web:FullTrackData><xsl:value-of select="//FullTrackData"/></web:FullTrackData>
                <web:Amount><xsl:value-of select="//Amount  * 100"/></web:Amount>
                <web:Currency><xsl:value-of select="//Currency"/></web:Currency>
            </web:Request>
        </web:Payment>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template xmlns:web="https://webapi.example.com" match="ReloadRequest">
        <web:Reload>
            <web:Request>
                <web:AccountName><xsl:value-of select="//AccountName"/></web:AccountName>
                <web:FullTrackData><xsl:value-of select="//FullTrackData"/></web:FullTrackData>
                <web:Amount><xsl:value-of select="//Amount  * 100"/></web:Amount>
                <web:Currency><xsl:value-of select="//Currency"/></web:Currency>
            </web:Request>
        </web:Reload>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template xmlns:web="https://webapi.example.com" match="RefundRequest">
        <web:Refund>
            <web:Request>
                <web:AccountName><xsl:value-of select="//AccountName"/></web:AccountName>
                <web:FullTrackData><xsl:value-of select="//FullTrackData"/></web:FullTrackData>
                <web:Amount><xsl:value-of select="//Amount  * 100"/></web:Amount>
                <web:Currency><xsl:value-of select="//Currency"/></web:Currency>
                <web:RollbackType><xsl:value-of select="//RollbackType"/></web:RollbackType>
                <web:RollbackRequestId><xsl:value-of select="//RollbackRequestId"/></web:RollbackRequestId>         
            </web:Request>
        </web:Refund>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template xmlns:web="https://webapi.example.com" match="BalanceRequest">
        <web:Balance>
            <web:Request>
                <web:AccountName><xsl:value-of select="//AccountName"/></web:AccountName>
                <web:FullTrackData><xsl:value-of select="//FullTrackData"/></web:FullTrackData>
            </web:Request>
        </web:Balance>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```